# values modified in javascript not getting updated in JSF PhaseListener

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, phaselistener

Initially `hold_mode` value is set to `0`, after `commandButton` click, it changed to 1 through JavaScript onclick event...but in PhaseListener beforePhase() method, the value is `0`. I did not understand why the value is still `0`. 
Can anyone please explain me on this.?

### info.xhtml

```
<h:form id="userForm">
<h:inputHidden id="hold_mode" value="0" />
<h:commandButton id="hold" style="width: 60px;" value="#{myForm.holdbtntitle}" disabled="#{myForm.holdbtn}"  action="#{myForm.hold}" actionListener="#{convo.holdListener}" onclick="return send(true,'3');"  rendered="#{myForm.holdpanelflg}"/>
```

### JavaScript

```
function send(confirmFlg,msgFlg) {
   isClicked = true;
   if(confirmFlg) {
      msg = 'From Hold';
      if(confirm(msg) == false) {
          isClicked = false;
          event.returnValue = false;
          return false;
       }
    }
    if(isClicked) {
       if(msgFlg == '3') {
          document.all.item('myForm:hold_mode').value='1';
       }
       pep_OpenWaitDirect('../../../html/common/printwait.xhtml');
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

### PhaseListener

```
public class RemoveValidateListener implements PhaseListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3556867423746720962L;

private FacesContext old = null;

public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Before "+e.getPhaseId());
    if(e.getPhaseId().equals(PhaseId.PROCESS_VALIDATIONS)) {
        UIComponent comp = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
        if(findHoldMode(comp)){

            old = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            removeValidatorsForComponentTree(comp);
        } 
    }
}

public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("After "+e.getPhaseId());
    if(e.getPhaseId().equals(PhaseId.PROCESS_VALIDATIONS)) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIComponent comp = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
        if(findHoldMode(comp)){

            StateManager stateManager = (StateManager)context.getApplication().getStateManager();
            stateManager.restoreView(old,old.getViewRoot().getViewId(),old.getViewRoot().getRenderKitId());
        }
    }
}

private boolean findHoldMode(UIComponent comp){
    boolean rtnFlg = false;
    List list = comp.getChildren();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        UIComponent temp = (UIComponent) list.get(i);
        if (!(temp instanceof HtmlBody)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            List<UIComponent> childList = temp.getChildren();
            for (int j = 0; j < childList.size(); j++) {
                UIComponent childTemp = (UIComponent) childList.get(j);
                if (!(childTemp instanceof HtmlPanelGrid)) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    List<UIComponent> child2List = childTemp.getChildren();
                    for (int k = 0; k < child2List.size(); k++) {
                        UIComponent child2Temp = (UIComponent) child2List.get(k);
                        if (!(child2Temp instanceof HtmlForm)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        UIComponent hold = child2Temp.findComponent(JsfBase.HOLD_MODE_COMPNAME);
                        if (hold == null) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (!(hold instanceof UIInput)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        Object mode = ((UIInput) hold).getValue();
                        if (mode == null || !(mode.toString().equals(JsfBase.HOLD_MODE_ON))) {
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            rtnFlg = true;
                            ((UIInput) hold).setValue("0");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rtnFlg;
}

private void removeValidatorsForComponentTree(UIComponent comp){
    removeValidators(comp);    
    List complist = comp.getChildren();

    if (complist.size()>0){    
        for(int i = 0; i < complist.size(); i++) {
            UIComponent uicom = (UIComponent) complist.get(i);
            removeValidatorsForComponentTree(uicom);
        }
    }

}

private void removeValidators(UIComponent comp){
    if(comp instanceof UIInput){
        removeValidator((UIInput)comp);
    }
}

public void removeValidator(UIInput comp){
    Validator[] validator = comp.getValidators();
    for(int i=0;i < validator.length;i++){
        comp.removeValidator(validator[i]);
    }
    if(comp.isRequired()){
        comp.setRequired(false);
    }
}
}
```

I tried this `<h:inputHidden id="hold_mode" value="0"  immediate="true" />`  and it works for the current screen but the problem is when I click the `commandButton` in other screens, the following exception occured
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: FacesContext already released`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got fixed after modified `PhaseListener`

1. Why I got `IllegalStateException` is as I have declared `FacesContext` object `old` globally. In that case, I had declared it inside `befoerPhase` method as we don't declare `FacesContext` globally..
2. Before code modification, what we did is we removed validators in `beforePhase` and we are restoring the view state in `afterPhase`, but it did not worked properly. So now I am saving the view state before validators removal in `beforePhase` instead of restoring it in `afterPhase`..

   ```
   public class RemoveValidateListener implements PhaseListener {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 3556867423746720962L;

       public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent e) {

           if (e.getPhaseId().equals(PhaseId.PROCESS_VALIDATIONS)) {

               FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
               UIComponent comp = context.getViewRoot();

               StateManager stateManager = (StateManager) context.getApplication().getStateManager();
               stateManager.saveView(context);

               if (findHoryuMode(comp)) {
                   removeValidatorsForComponentTree(comp);
               } 
           }
       }

       public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent e) {

       }
   ```

   }